# Focus on select element also opens it: can that be prevented?

Tags: javascript, forms

Simple, two input interface using a table: each row shows a US state and then a sales tax value. The last row in the table has a dropdown for the state, and a textbox.

When the user commits their entry, I add a row to the table, plug in the values, then I blank both of the controls for the next entry. (An ajax call writes the values to the database, but that's not relevant here.)

The dropdown is first, so after the commit I'd like to put the focus on it, but when I do the dropdown opens. I need that to *not* happen.

Can I put focus on the select control without it opening?

[image]

Comment: Try `event.preventDefault()` in the `onFocus` method

Comment: Alas, no. Still dropped open. Thank you, though.

Comment: Could you provide some code?